# Sign in count per day in Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

Is there any way to find out how many unique logins per day a user has?

We can track a user to find out how many sign_in's or when the user signed in with:

```
User.last.sign_in_count
```

or

```
User.last.last_sign_in_at
```

But not how many time he logged in each day.

Answer (score 4):

Here is what I did in my rails app:

I created a new model to track each visit

```
rails g model Visit user_id:integer user_ip:inet user_email:string
```

Then

```
rake db:migrate
```

Next I created a controller to track sessions with

```
app/controllers/track_sessions_controller.rb
```

[info about devise session controller](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/sessions_controller.rb)

Then I added code to run after each successful login

```
class TrackSessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  after_filter :after_login, :only => :create

  def after_login
    Visit.create!(user_id: current_user.id, user_ip: current_user.current_sign_in_ip, user_email: current_user.email)
  end
end
```

Then update this section of your routes.rb

```
devise_for :users
```

to

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :sessions => "track_sessions" }
```

If you wanted to see how many unique logins per day a user has, you can now do something like this:

```
User.all.each do |user|
  logins_per_day(user.id) 
end

def logins_per_day(user_id)
  dates_visited = Visit.where(user_id: user_id).select('distinct created_at').all.collect{|x| x[:created_at].to_date}
  puts "************* USER ID #{user_id} *************"
  dates_visited.group_by {|date| date}.map {|date_visited, times_visited| puts "Date Visited: #{date_visited} Times Visited: #{times_visited.count}"}
end
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Do you have any open source project based on this? How did you create views for this?

Answer (score 1):

what you can do is create a table that will work like a log, there you input every login, or, what you can do is, create a .txt at yor soucer code that get de login after they pass the login control and insert to the .txt username and date, but the bad side is the log will be at the computer.

if you choose use a tablein sql, acces or whatever you wanna, just one select solve.

select count(*) from table_log_login where user = 'user' and date = 'yyyy-mm-dd';

Answer (score 0):

I'm having trouble understanding what you want, so:

If you want to count the number of logins per day, you can create an after filter for the login method where you check the date (this is assuming you have a table where you track the number of logins with a date).

If you want to know the number of consecutive days your user is logging in, you can do the same but instead save a start date, and an end date, so you know when the "streak" will be over.

PS: if you have trouble with english, post both in english and any other language you're fluent in, so someone can properly translate.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, sorry, i understand well but dont write so good, than lets try in two languages.

When you log in at your program, you insert at log table in a database and when the program close, update the row, insert with login start and update with login end, you can use smalldatetime in sqlserver or datetime in mysql, so, you can select without problem the day, hour or minute of logins.

think it:
insert into tb_login(cod_login, cd_user, dt_start) values('26','5','2013-12-30 08:02');
note: you need have a columns that accept null, the columns is " dt_end "

than you update
update set dt_end = '2013-12-30 10:10' from tb_login where cod_login = '26';